# select without displaying null

Tags: mysql

please don't get annoy with this question but I have try it without selected null value and still nothing

The problem is I am trying to select everything from sub_qua without selecting 0...

Hope this question not too stupid. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean ``0`` or ``NULL``?

Comment: If it is ``NULL``, use the ``IS NOT NULL`` clause. Otherwise just normal comparison.

Comment: How would it read null if it's numeric in MySQL?

Comment: Basically I am trying to select everything from sub_qua but I don't want to select the 0

Comment: Thanks Ben but this is always design for mobile users as well because it responsive unfortunately they  haven't got an alternative for crtl + k here and also thanks to the person that fix the table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be so simple if I don't misinterpret your question

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE Sub_qua != 0
```